# Stop page from jumping to where I click inside a scroll box

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a scroll box on the lefthand side of my page with 50 buttons inside that toggle divs on the righthand side of the page, outside of the scroll box. The top buttons inside the scroll box work great. When I scroll to a button, say, at the very bottom of INSIDE the scroll box, it will jump the entire page view down to where that button *would* be without the scroll box. Any idea on how to stop this? Searching this has brought up only answers on anchor tags and this does not contain those.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post what you have done so far. 
If you need help please use the following guide stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I derived this from your question. The div only get toggle when you click the text on the button and not the button...this is something you can fix (hint: the padding/margin of the button and label).
Otherwise, you may need to try looking into the height of the scrollbox or if the html/body is overflowing. It's even better if you show your work, so we can help you further.

```css
<style>body {
  background: silver;
}

div.ex1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 20vh;
  /* here is probably what you need */
  overflow: auto;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=radio]+div {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+div {
  display: block;
}

</style>
```

```html
<h2 style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">overflow: scroll/auto:</h2>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="ex1">
    <button><label for="1">Button1</label></button>
    <button><label for="2">Button2</label></button>
    <button><label for="3">Button3</label></button>
    <button><label for="4">Button4</label></button>
    <button><label for="5">Button5</label></button>
    <button><label for="6">Button6</label></button>
    <button><label for="7">Button7</label></button>
    <button><label for="8">Button8</label></button>
    <button><label for="9">Button9</label></button>
    <button><label for="10">Button10</label></button>
    <button><label for="11">Button11</label></button>
    <button><label for="12">Button12</label></button>
    <button><label for="13">Button13</label></button>
    <button><label for="14">Button14</label></button>
    <button><label for="15">Button15</label></button>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align: center; margin: auto;">
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="1" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 1</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="2" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 2</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="3" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 3</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="4" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 4</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="5" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 5</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="6" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 6</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="7" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 7</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="8" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 8</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="9" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 9</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="10" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 10</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="11" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 11</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="12" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 12</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="13" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 13</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="14" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 14</div>
            </span>
    <span>
                <input type="radio" id="15" name="toggleDiv">
                <div>This is div 15</div>
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```